# How to design a square wave inverter circuit without an op amp

Tags: ac, 555, npn, inverting-amplifier

I am using an NE555 timer circuit to generate a 0 to 12 volt 10kHz square wave.

I would like to invert that square wave (so inverted signal is 0 when original is 12V and 12V when the original is 0 V.)

I used an NPN transistor that creates a distorted inverted wave.

Is there a simple way to make a clean inverter circuit for this AC signal?

Here are pictures of the circuit and output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Question: what do you think Q1 does?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Q1 is the npn transistor that does an inversion; this is shown by the "distorted" inverted signal (the one in black). I want to make this black signal a clean square wave

Comment: Replace the transistor with an inverter?

Comment: @Justme You mean an OP AMP inverter? I am trying to avoid that because an OP AMP has some power inefficiencies.

Comment: @user758469 No, I don't mean an op-amp, as you specifically said you did not want an op-amp.

Comment: @user758469 exactly, you got that one right, but you've got to realize that the reason for the "roundness" in your curve is due to the things around Q1 (and Q1 itself).

Comment: Might help if you explained why you are doing this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So you mean I should tweak the resistor / capacitor values until I get a better output?

Comment: I don't think your transistor is actually a 2N3904. What model is it that is being invoked?

Comment: @HandyHowie So basically, I am making an DC to AC converter, which requires two switching signals (I know that the oscillator can act like a DC to AC, but I am asked to do this by my professor/supervisor)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am using the standard 2N3904 model found in LTSpice; I right-clicked the transistor and chose 2N3904

Comment: @user758469 your question is still interesting, but the fact that you want to make a DC/AC inverter with a 555 does make me a bit sad. Don't do this to yourself! Basically all modern micrcocontrollers (even the 1€/piece ones) have PWM units that can produce your square wave and its inverse out of the box, and you'd just use that to drive a MOSFET push/pull power stage (an H-bridge). Often they also do dead time between switching the voltages, so that you never get shoot-through! There's a lot power converter/motor control-optimized microcontrollers, which are basically ASICs for DC/AC.

Comment: @user758469 What exactly do you plan to drive with this second output circuit? It matters ***a lot***.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Even with 3.3V or 5V MCU signals he'd likely need a gate driver circuit to drive high current and give >10V gate drive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I get with the 2N3904 driven with a clean 12V square wave (note that the 555 model is not very accurate, but that doesn't matter here). Collector is open except for the 10K resistor to +12:

There is a slight delay in the rise due to charge storage effects but no such waveform.

[image]

Is there a hidden capacitor or probe model or something of that ilk not shown? It would take a huge capacitance (~10nF) to cause that effect.

Here is the simple circuit:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 400 16 288 16
WIRE 288 128 288 96
WIRE 672 128 288 128
WIRE 288 144 288 128
WIRE 400 144 400 16
WIRE 80 192 64 192
WIRE 128 192 80 192
WIRE 224 192 208 192
WIRE 64 208 64 192
FLAG 288 240 0
FLAG 400 224 0
FLAG 64 288 0
FLAG 288 128 Vcollector
FLAG 80 192 Vin
FLAG 672 192 0
SYMBOL res 224 176 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 272 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1K
SYMBOL voltage 400 128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL voltage 64 192 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 12 10n 10n 10n 50u 100u)
SYMBOL npn 224 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N3904
SYMBOL cap 656 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 10n
TEXT 30 312 Left 2 !.tran 300u
```

Comment: I am not sure; I just right-clicked on the transistor and chose the model directly from LTSPice. IS that what you did?

Comment: Yes, it's the default model npn->2N3904  which is the NXP model .model 2N3904 NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100 Bf=300 IKF=0.4 XTB=1.5 BR=4 CJC=4E-12 CJE=8E-12 RB=20 RC=0.1 RE=0.1 TR=250E-9 TF=350E-12 ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 Vceo=40 Icrating=200m mfg=NXP)

Comment: ok I will try simulating again

Comment: You can save the above as an .asc file and open it directly.

Comment: If you have the gate of a hidden MOSFET connected to the inverter output, that would explain your results 100%. You have the models there- why?

Comment: I got it!! As you mentioned in your answer, I changed the collector resistor from 1k to 10k and the clean waveforms

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I still think something is awry. If you have the hidden MOSFET you'll need a better gate driver circuit.